# Reactive Extensions Subscribe calling await

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I want to perform an async call based for each *event* raised by a Reactive Extensions Observable. I'm also trying to keep everything synchronized as I want the async call to finish before the next event is handled.

How would one go about doing something similar to the following? I say similar as the code below does not compile.

```
settingsChangedInMemory
    .Subscribe(async _ => {
        var settings = Extract();
        await SaveSettings(settings);
    });
```

I'm not sure if it changes anything, but I would need to Subscribe to multiple Observables. For example another subscription like this.

```
settingsChangedOnDisk
    .Subscribe(async _ => {
        var settings = await ReadSettings(settings);
        Apply(settings);
    });
```

How would you use Reactive Extensions to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about:

```
settingsChangedInMemory
    .SelectMany(async _ => await SaveSettings(Extract()))
    .Subscribe(x => Apply(x));
```

Never put an `async` in a `Subscribe`, you always want to put it in a `SelectMany` instead.

Comment: Is this still true as of RX 2.0 (which predates your answer)?  The above code now seems to compile and there's an example from the RX team here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx of a Subscribe(async () => ...)

Comment: Absolutely still true

Comment: Do you mind elaborating Paul? They explicitly state they support async in subscribe, and your response doesn't really explain why the developers of Reactive are wrong.

Comment: `async void` methods can be called anywhere `void` methods can be called. Therefore `Subscribe` supports async methods because the methods are void. You  can't await a Disposable/Subscription anyways. If you need something like that, use `SelectMany`, etc, first, and then subscribe.

Comment: Can the `async` safely go in a `Select`, as well as in a `SelectMany`?

Comment: @StuartHallows no it can't, select doesn't have an overload that accepts a Task<T>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new `ForEachAsync` method released in Reactive Extensions (Rx) 2.0 like so:

```
await observable
    .ForEachAsync(async x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    });
```

`ForEachAsync` returns a `Task<T>` which completes when the observable completes. More information in my blog post [here](https://rehansaeed.com/reactive-extensions-part5-awaiting-observables/) or this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rxteam/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now/) by the reactive extensions team.