# How to Subscribe with async method in Rx?

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have following code:

```
IObservable<Data> _source;

...

_source.Subscribe(StoreToDatabase);

private async Task StoreToDatabase(Data data) {
    await dbstuff(data);
}
```

However, this does not compile. Is there any way how to observe data asynchronously? I tried `async void`, it works, but I feel that given solution is not feasible.

I also checked [Reactive Extensions Subscribe calling await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843000/reactive-extensions-subscribe-calling-await), but it does not answer my question (I do not care about the `SelectMany` result.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactive Extensions Subscribe calling await](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843000/reactive-extensions-subscribe-calling-await)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have to care about the `SelectMany` result.  The answer is still the same... though you need your task to have a return type (i.e. `Task<T>`, not `Task`).

`Unit` is essentially equivalent to `void`, so you can use that:

```
_source.SelectMany(StoreToDatabase).Subscribe();

private async Task<Unit> StoreToDatabase(Data data)
{
    await dbstuff(data);
    return Unit.Default;
}
```

This `SelectMany` overload accepts a `Func<TSource, Task<TResult>` meaning the resulting sequence will not complete until the task is completed.

Comment: But do at least put an `OnError` handler in your subscribe method. If you dont, and either `_source` errors or `StoreToDatabase` throws you will have your application fall over, or end up in an unknown state.

Comment: Can we get rid of the `Unit`?

Answer (score 12):

Late answer, but I think that the following extension methods correctly encapsulate what Charles Mager proposed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37412422/11410):

```
public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
                         Func<Task> asyncAction, Action<Exception> handler = null)
{
    Func<T,Task<Unit>> wrapped = async t =>
    {
        await asyncAction();
        return Unit.Default;
    };
    if(handler == null)
        return source.SelectMany(wrapped).Subscribe(_ => { });
    else
        return source.SelectMany(wrapped).Subscribe(_ => { }, handler);
}

public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
                         Func<T,Task> asyncAction, Action<Exception> handler = null)
{
    Func<T, Task<Unit>> wrapped = async t =>
    {
        await asyncAction(t);
        return Unit.Default;
    };
    if(handler == null)
        return source.SelectMany(wrapped).Subscribe(_ => { });
    else
        return source.SelectMany(wrapped).Subscribe(_ => { }, handler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using TPL DataFlow to control back pressure and have used it to solve this problem.

The key part is `ITargetBlock<TInput>.AsObserver()` - [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d6b460124131a12a638872d31a70c366d3585f88/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlock.cs#L2664).

```
// Set a block to handle each element
ITargetBlock<long> targetBlock = new ActionBlock<long>(async p =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received {p}");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished handling {p}");
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 });

// Generate an item each second for 10 seconds
var sequence = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(10);

// Subscribe with an observer created from the target block.
sequence.Subscribe(targetBlock.AsObserver());

// Await completion of the block
await targetBlock.Completion;
```

The important part here is that the ActionBlock's bounded capacity is set to 1. This prevents the block from receiving more than one item at a time and [will block OnNext](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d6b460124131a12a638872d31a70c366d3585f88/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlock.cs#L2694) if an item is already being processed!

My big surprise here was that it can be safe to call `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` inside your subscription. Obviously, if you have called `ObserverOnDispatcher()` or similar you will probably hit deadlocks. Be careful!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run the Store Data Procedure, possibly some other procedure and asynchronously await the completion or partial result.  How about Create constructor shown here:

```
IObservable<Int32> NotifyOfStoringProgress = 
Observable.Create(
(Func<IObserver<Int32>, Task>)
(async (ObserverToFeed) =>
{
    ObserverToFeed.OnNext(-1);    
    Task StoreToDataBase = Task.Run(()=> {;});
    ObserverToFeed.OnNext(0);    
    ;;
    await StoreToDataBase;
    ObserverToFeed.OnNext(1);
    ;;
}));

NotifyOfStoringProgress.Subscribe(onNext: Notification => {;});
```